# 'render' is not defined when running create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When I am using create react app when compliling I get the following errors ./src/Grid.js
 "Line 3:  Your render method should have return statement" and "Line 5:  'render' is not defined"
this is the contents of the the Grid.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Grid extends Component {
    render(){
        return <p>Hello, World</p>;
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

I can't see that is wrong here? any help appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from './Grid.js';

class App extends Component 
{
  render()
  {
    return(
      <div> 
        <Grid />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is where I am using the component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Where ReactDOM render is used

Comment: What happens if you use a functional component, e.g. `const Grid = () => <p>Hello, World</p>;`

Comment: try render() {
  return (some value)

Comment: can you show where you are rendering this component?

Comment: I've appended where I am rendering the component in the original question

Comment: I'm suspecting something hasn't downloaded properly when you created the create-react-app.  Have you tried running `npm install` within the app, or perhaps just starting again and importing the files you created?

Answer (score 10):

You are missing `import {render} from 'react-dom';`.

Comment: is it `react-dom` or `react-router-dom`?

Answer (score 0):

> It should be:
>
> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
>
> class Grid extends Component {
>     render(){
>         return(<p>Hello, World</p>);
>     }
> }
>
> export default Grid;
> ```

The above quote no longer applies.

I tried your exact code for Grid.js and App.js from the question and it works well on my machine. Whatever reason why your thing isn't working isn't in your Grid.js or App.js.

Comment: No thats not a necesity

Comment: If you're returning a one line component, brackets aren't necessary

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the compile issue even with the parenthesis around the jsx :(

Comment: If I remove the `<Grid />`  from App.js and remove the Grid import and render some plain HTML in the render function it works fine.

Comment: super interesting... can you please replace the "<Grid />" with "<p>Hello, World</p>" and see what we got? If it does work, can you please delete Grid.js and create another component in its place and see what you got? That stuff sometimes works.

Comment: Wow I created a new file with the exactly the same code for the component and it compiles fine. strange.

Answer (score -1):

Still no real explanation for this. Copying the component code in to a newly created file compiles correctly. Very strange indeed.